# Orchard - Can't find the Resource defined in ResourceManifest.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have a custom there, where I try to require some of my css and js files via the ResourceManifest.cs file - I keep into running a quite weird issue tough.

I get the following error:

*a 'script' named 'FoundationScript' could not be found*

This is my ResourceManifest.cs:

```
using Orchard.UI.Resources;

namespace Themes.TestTheme
{
  public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider
  {
    public void BuildManifest(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {

      var manifest = builder.Add();

      manifest.DefineStyle("Foundation").SetUrl("foundation.min.css");
      manifest.DefineScript("FoundationScript").SetUrl("foundation.min.js");

    }  
  }
}
```

In the Layout.cshtml, I have following:

```
@{
  Script.Require("ShapesBase");
  Script.Require("FoundationScript");

  Style.Include("site.css");
  Style.Require("Foundation");

}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, that the project `Themes` has a problem with the dynamic compile mechanism of Orchard (i don't know what is wrong exactly) because it resides in folder `Themes`. Even if you define a class inside the `Themes` assembly, it will result in an error telling you there is no such class in that assembly.

**solution** :

Try re-generating your theme with `/CreateProject:true` and `/IncludeInSolution:true` parameters as follows:

```
codegen theme TestTheme /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true /BasedOn :TheThemeMachine
```

It will create your theme in a separate `project` and orchard will pick your registered `ResourceManifest`.

Hope this helps.